# Ruby extract method from if block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using [jira-ruby gem](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby) to create an jira issue using my app. The ticket on Jira board should be created in one or two board depend on which action was triggered before. For example when new member was added to the repo it should create two tickets in two separate boards (support and security). I've to use client.Issue.build twice (this is a gem method) so I need to do something like:

```
  def call
    if SUPPORTBOARD_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES.include?(webhook.action_type_class)
      issue = client.Issue.build
      issue.save(support_ticket_class.new(webhook))
    end

    if SECURIY_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES.include?(webhook.action_type_class)
      issue = client.Issue.build
      issue.save(security_ticket_class.new(webhook))
    end
  end
```

Because of RSpec issues with stubbing `client.Issue.build` ([here is related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61325058/rspec-for-jira-ticket-creation-receive-message-chain-with-error-true-does-not?noredirect=1#comment108488671_61325058)) I want to extract to separate method below part from if bloc:

```
issue = client.Issue.build
issue.save(...)
```

How to pass `support_ticket_class.new(webhook)` or `security_ticket_class.new(webhook)` in `issue.save()` depended of if block above and extract it to another method.

Answer (score 2):

create a method accepting ticket class and webhook

```rb
def create_issue(ticket_class, webhook)
  issue = client.Issue.build
  issue.save(ticket_class.new(webhook))
end
```

and then call this method passing ticket class and webhook

```rb
if SUPPORTBOARD_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES.include?(webhook.action_type_class)
  create_issue(support_ticket_class, webhook)
end

if SECURIY_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES.include?(webhook.action_type_class)
  create_issue(security_ticket_class, webhook)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have duplication in your code.

Why not create a hash that maps `action_type_class` to the corresponding ticket class(es)? Something like this should  work: (replace `MAPPING`  with a more descriptive name)

```
MAPPING = {
  foo_action: [support_ticket_class, security_ticket_class],
  bar_action: [support_ticket_class],
  baz_action: [security_ticket_class]
}
```

You can then fetch the ticket classes for the action type and create the corresponding tickets in a loop:

```
def call
  MAPPING.fetch(webhook.action_type_class, []).each do |ticket_class|
    issue = client.Issue.build
    issue.save(ticket_class.new(webhook))
  end
end
```